# Using TempData with Post Redirect Get pattern

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

There are a number of folks that advocate using TempData with the PRG pattern in .NET Core 2.2.x.

From what I understand, this line of code stores data:

```
 TempData["foo"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
```

And the following reconstitutes the model and then deletes it from the TempData construct:

```
string s = (string)TempData["Model"];
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelType>(s);
```

So given this transient nature of TempData, imagine the following PRG construct.  The user POSTs to the `UserInfo` action, which packages the model into TempData and redirects to a `UserInfo` GET.  The GET `UserInfo` reconstitutes the model and displays the view.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UserInfo(DataCollectionModel model) {
    TempData["Model"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    return RedirectToAction("UserInfo");
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UserInfo() {
    string s = (string)TempData["Model"];
    DataCollectionModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataCollectionModel>(s);
    return View(model);
}
```

The user is now on the /Controller/UserInfo page.  If the user pressed F5 to refresh the page, the TempData["Model"] would no longer be there and the GET on `UserInfo` would fail.  The fix might be to store the model in TempData after reading it, but wouldn't that result in leaking memory?

Am I missing something?

Comment: `TempData` is often used for sensitive information. It is not required for PRG.

Comment: @Jasen What method would you use to move information from POST to GET?  (i don't have a database, therefore I can't use IDs to pass around).

Comment: Session state would be the logical alternative to TempData, if you want to keep the data around after the first access.

Comment: @DaveCluderay The app will be setting on multiple servers, so single machine sesison state won't work and I think it would an overkill to introduce distributed cache just for the PRG pattern.  Probably going to go with cookies or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TempData can be used for storing transient data . It is useful for redirection, when data is needed for more than a single request.When an object in a TempDataDictionary is read, it will be marked for deletion at the end of that request.

That means if you put something on TempData like

```
TempData["value"] = "someValueForNextRequest";
```

And on another request you access it, the value will be there but as soon as you read it, the value will be marked for deletion:

```
//second request, read value and is marked for deletion
object value = TempData["value"];

//third request, value is not there as it was deleted at the end of the second request
TempData["value"] == null
```

The Peek and Keep methods allow you to read the value without marking it for deletion. Say we get back to the first request where the value was saved to TempData.

With Peek you get the value without marking it for deletion with a single call, see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.peek?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2):

```
//second request, PEEK value so it is not deleted at the end of the request
object value = TempData.Peek("value");

//third request, read value and mark it for deletion
object value = TempData["value"];
```

With Keep you specify a key that was marked for deletion that you want to keep. Retrieving the object and later on saving it from deletion are 2 different calls. See [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.keep?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_TempDataDictionary_Keep_System_String_)

```
//second request, get value marking it from deletion
object value = TempData["value"];
//later on decide to keep it
TempData.Keep("value");

//third request, read value and mark it for deletion
object value = TempData["value"];
```

You can use Peek when you always want to retain the value for another request. Use Keep when retaining the value depends on additional logic.

Make the following changes in your Get action

```
public IActionResult UserInfo()
    {
        //The First method ,
        string s = (string)TempData.Peek("Model");

        //The Second method
        string s = (string)TempData["Model"]; 
        TempData.Keep("Model");

        if(s==null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            User model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(s);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am confused by your terminology in the last code snippet.  When you say `First method` and `Second method` - do you mean that both methods will work?

Comment: Yes , the both methods will work, according to the comparison of the Peek and Keep methods above, using the first method in your scenario is better than the second.